# 3 Column Layout: Fixed Positions for Divs

Tags: html, css

So I'm currently working on a 3 column site template and managed to rearrange the divs for SEO purposes. My only problem is that it looks horrible when its not yet 100% loaded.

This is how it looks when it's not yet fully loaded
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSaMh.png

100% loaded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smclN.png

So is it possible to make the position of the div fixed?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">I'm first</div>
        <div id="side_a">I'm second</div>
    </div>
    <div id="side_b">I'm third</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;}
#content-wrapper{float: left;}
#content {width: 400px;float: right;}
#side_a {width: 200px;float: left;} 
#side_b {float: left;width: 200px;}
```

Overview: http://jsfiddle.net/avzLK/

Comment: What's the issue in your demo? If I remove content all DIV, they stay exactly where they're expected to be...

Comment: There's actually no problem in the demo. My problem is that the main content div is not centered when the page is not yet fully loaded.

Comment: I still don't get it, that means you're hard-loading a template structure (i.e: the `DIV #side_a`) instead of pulling it into an already existent container? Your demo has no main issues, it's just you should pull content **into it** instead of creating it on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think if you set

```
    #content-wrapper{float:left; width:600px}
```

then your     #content will float to the right even before     #side_a is loaded, because it knows that the parent is 600px wide.

Comment: Thank you!! Setting the width of content-wrapper fixed the issue.